# Is it possible to determine the Security Protocol used in a WCF web service client?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF web service using NetHttpBinding. I know I can control which protocols are available/used by using:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls|SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But is it possible to determine which protocol was actually used after make a service call?

I could explicitly set it to one protocol, then loop and make a call to see if it is successful, and repeat but that seems really clunky/slow. Any better ideas for doing this?